# how to find the general series solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

The questions states to find the general series solution about the point is $x=0$  and the equation is $(x^2-1)y''-2xy'+2y=0$. State the domain of validity.

I know that to begin we assume the general power series solution.

Firstly having trouble understanding how to determine the domain of validity. I arrived at the conclusion that $|x|<1$ but am uncertain on how exactly that is right.

The second issue i am having is when i arrive at the point where all the summations have the same power moving forward and finding the coefficients are a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dividing the coefficient of $y'$ and the coefficient of $y$ by the coefficient of $y''$ we get 
$$ P(x) = \frac{2x}{x^2 -1} \quad \text{and} \quad Q(x)=\frac{2}{x^2 -1},$$
both of which exist for values of $|x| >1$.

The ODE you're trying to solve is very well known in the literature as a modified version of the Legendre ODE. Here I provide a solution for the form 
$$ y(x) = (1-x^2)y''  -2xy' + \alpha(\alpha+1),$$
which should help you to solve the given form of your ODE.

\begin{align*}
       (1-x^{2}) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n-2} -2x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n a_{n}x^{n-1} + \alpha(\alpha+1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}x^{n} &= 0\\
       \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n-2} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n} - 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n a_{n}x^{n} + \alpha(\alpha+1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n} &= 0\\
       \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_{n}x^{n} - 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n a_{n}x^{n} + \alpha(\alpha+1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n} &= 0 \\
       \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left((n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} - n(n-1)a_{n} -2na_{n} + \alpha(\alpha+1)a_{n}\right)x^{n} &= 0
      \end{align*}
                        \begin{align*}
       \implies a_{n+2}  &= \frac{n(n-1)a_{n} + 2na_{n} - \alpha(\alpha+1)a_{n}}{(n+2)(n+1)} \\
       &= \frac{a_{n}((n-\alpha)(n+\alpha+1))}{(n+2)(n+1)} \quad n \ge 1.
      \end{align*}
\begin{align*}
              a_{2} &= \frac{a_{0}(-\alpha)(\alpha+1)}{2}\\
              a_{4} &= \frac{a_{0}(\alpha+1)(\alpha-2)(\alpha+3)}{4} \\
              a_{6} &= \frac{a_{0}-(\alpha+1)(\alpha-2)(\alpha+3)(\alpha-4)(\alpha+5)}{6!}
             \end{align*}
\begin{align*}
                   a_{3} &= \frac{-a_{1}(\alpha-1)(\alpha+2)}{3!}\\
                   a_{5} &= \frac{a_{1}(\alpha-1)(\alpha+2)(\alpha-3)(\alpha+4)}{8} \\
                   a_{7} &= \frac{-a_{1}(\alpha-1)(\alpha+2)(\alpha-3)(\alpha+4)(\alpha-5)(\alpha+6)}{7!}
                  \end{align*}
                            This leads to the recursion relationship 
                                    \begin{align*}
             &\textbf{EVEN} : a_{n} = a_{2k} = \frac{(-1)^{k}a_{0}\alpha (\alpha+2k-1)(\alpha+2k-3)\dots(\alpha+1)(\alpha-2)\dots(\alpha-2k+2)}{(2k)!}  , \ k\ge 1\\
             &\textbf{ODD} : a_{n} = a_{2k+1} = \frac{(-1)^{k} a_{1}(\alpha+2k)(\alpha+2k-2)\dots(\alpha+2)(\alpha-1)\dots(\alpha-2k+1)}{(2k+1)!} \ \ ,k \ge 1.
            \end{align*}
                    Therefore we write the series solution as
                    \begin{gather*}
      y(x) = y_{0} y_1(x) + y_{0}' y_2(x),\\
      \text{where } \quad y_{1}(x) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}a_{0}\alpha (\alpha+2k-1)(\alpha+2n-3)\dots(\alpha+1)(\alpha-2)\dots(\alpha-2k+2)}{(2k)!} \\
      \text{and} \quad y_{2}(x) = x + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k} a_{1}(\alpha+2k)(\alpha+2k-2)\dots(\alpha+2)(\alpha-1)\dots(\alpha-2k+1)}{(2k+1)!}
     \end{gather*}

At a first glance your ODE should have a slightly easier solution ,but very similar to the one which I'm providing.

Comment: Yes i completed the question an i was able to get a similar solution

Answer (score 0):

Legendre equation is given as:
$$(1-x^2)u''-2xu'+\nu(\nu+1)u=0~~~(1)$$
Whose standard solution is given as
$$u(x)=C_1 P_{\nu}(x)+ C_2Q_\nu(x)]$$
In he given case the ODE is
$$(1-x^2)y''+2xy'-2y=0~~~~(2)$$
In (1) if we change $x$ to $-x$ the solution of (2) can be written as
$$y(x)=C_1 P_{\nu}(-x)+C_2 Q_{\nu}(-x)$$
where $$\nu^2+ \nu=- \implies \nu=\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{7}}{2}.$$